# Converse of measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis

I know that if $f$ if measurable on $A$ , then $f^2$, $\frac{1}{f}$ and $\sqrt{f}$ are also measurable. BUt is ithe converse also true ? Is there any counterexample to this?

Comment: For $\frac1f$, are you assuming $f$ is non-zero? For $\sqrt{f}$, are you assuming $f$ is non-negative?

Comment: yes , they are assumed to be like this or the function will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is never zero, and $1/f$ is measurable, then $\frac1{1/f} = f$ is measurable.

If $f$ is never negative, and $\sqrt{f\,}$ is measurable, then ${\sqrt{f\,}\,}^2 = f$ is measurable.

If $f^2$ is measurable, then $\sqrt{f^2} = |f|$ is measurable. So if we assume that $f$ is non-negative, $f$ will be measurable, but it will not be true in general. (Consider $f = 2\chi - 1$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic function of an unmeasurable set, for instance. Then $f^2 = 1$ is measurable, but $f$ is not.)

Comment: That last point is possible to strengthen a bit. Of course, if $f$ is non-positive and $|f|$ is measurable, then $f$ is also measurable. My gut says that if the set of points where $f$ is negative is measurable, and $|f|$ is measurable, then $f$ is measurable. But don't quote me on that.

Comment: $f^{-1}(A)=[(|f|^{-1}(A))\cap (f\leq 0)^{c})] \cup ]((|f|^{-1}(-A))\cap (f\leq 0)]$ and $-A$ is a Borel set whenever $A$ is Borel so your guess is right.